# What are 1A_g and 1B_u excitons?

Tags: polymers, photochemistry

I was going through a paper on organic LED chemistry [1]. I saw that the authors referred to "$1A_g$" and "$1B_u$" excitons (and also "$2A_g$" and "$2B_u$" excitons), terms which I don't really understand because I am from an engineering background. The terms are used on the 2nd-to-last paragraph of page 4 of the paper.

Can anyone help me understand this terminology?

[1] [W. Barford, R. J. Bursill, and R. W. Smith, *Phys. Rev. B* **2002**, *66*, 115205](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.66.115205)

Comment: What is the paper?  Please consider editing your question to include at least a link to it.  Even better would be to both link and then excerpt a paragraph that uses the terms you are confused by.

Comment: Also, it appears you cross-posted your question to physics.se: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241852/what-are-1ag-and-1bu-excitons  Please DO NOT do that.  Ask only in one place.

Comment: You're looking at symbols that describe the symmetry of the excitons. Have a look [here](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Theoretical_Chemistry/Symmetry/Character_Tables_for_Symmetry_Groups) for so-called character tables that decipher the symbols. All of this falls under the broader category of group theory.